How to bulk export business rules from Stibo STEP?
in a client's Stibo STEP system I am tasked to analyze and document the business rules that have piled up over the years. So to find cross-references between them I need to export them in a readable format, specifically the binds, dependencies and the code itself.
So far I managed to export them via an outbound Endpoint as STEPXML, with the option Business rules and Libraries enabled, but while some of the exported metadata (i.e. the dependencies) is structured and readable in the exported STEPXML, the actual javaScript is not included.  I assume it is in the content of the  tag, which is garbled/encrypted (?).
There is also the way of selecting a single BR and "Export in Editable Format" via context menu, but this seems to work for one rule at a time only.
